# How to alter values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column named "Zip Code" and all the values for this column read as such:

```
    ZIP Code        City    County
0   ZIP Code 02108  Boston  Suffolk
```

I need to delete "Zip Code" from each value of column "Zip Code" in all rows, so it would be purely integer and read:

```
    ZIP Code        City    County
0   02108           Boston  Suffolk
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you may just `strip` it

```
df['ZIP Code'] = df['ZIP Code'].str.strip('ZIP Code')
```

---

Since `len('ZIP Code ')` is `9`, you can also just ignore the first 9 characters by `slicing`

```
df['ZIP Code'].str[9:]
```

Comment: Don't forget the space after the `'ZIP Code'`... `'ZIP Code '`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this in addition to what rafaelc answered:

```
df['ZIP Code'] = df['ZIP Code'].str.split('ZIP Code', 1).str[1]
```

Basically, it just splits and keeps the latter half of the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

#### `slice`

If there is always going to be a `'ZIP Code '` in front

```
df['ZIP Code'] = df['ZIP Code'].str[9:]
```

---

#### `replace`

```
df['ZIP Code'] = df['ZIP Code'].str.replace('ZIP Code ', '')
```

---

#### `rsplit`

```
df['ZIP Code'] = df['ZIP Code'].str.rsplit(' ', 1).str[1]
```